# Проблема с приведением типов после linq запроса

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Поясню: Есть длинный текст, который хранится в базе. При выборе книги по ID этот текст должен отобразиться на странице, разбившись на "страницы". Разбивается текст по точкам. Страница должна состоять из 10 таких разбиений. Проблема: при выборе на странице появляется вот такое разочарование

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+ListPartition`1[System.String]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.String[]'.

Изначально метод контроллера возвращал весь массив разбитых строк, а представление в качестве модели принимало тип string[], чтобы все это дело вывести. После попытки разбить массив с помощью linq столкнулся с этой ошибкой.

метод контроллера:

int PageText=10;

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id, int textPage = 1)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            Book book = await repository.Books.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.BookID == id);

            char[] delimiterChars = { '.' };
            string text = book.BookText;
            string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);

            return View(words
                    .Skip((textPage - 1) * PageText)
                    .Take(PageText));

        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

представление:

```html
@model string[]

<div>
    @foreach (string word in Model)
    {
        <p>word</p>
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
```